# Visual Studio Community 2017 "add package" when pressing Ctrl+Dot

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community

In Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3, when you have a type that doesn't exist in your project, VS will search the package sources and give "add package xxx" suggestions, like this:
[image: VS2015 feature]

But in VS2017 Community, this feature is gone. Is there any option to turn it on? Or it's totally removed? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is disabled by default, you need to enable it in VS2017.

From [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/03/08/optimize-your-productivity-with-net-in-visual-studio-2017-2/):

> **Add using/Imports for types in reference assemblies/NuGet packages** –
>   if you type an unrecognized type, we will search for it in your
>   reference assemblies and on NuGet.org and offer a quick fix to add the
>   using/Imports. **This feature is off by default**; to enable it go to
>   Tools > Options > Text Editor > [C#/Basic] > Advanced > Suggest usings
>   for types in reference assemblies and Suggest usings for types in
>   NuGet packages. Enabling the latter option will download 10 MB of a
>   NuGet index on your machine and it will take several seconds to
>   complete (this will not affect your workflow in VS, but it does means
>   you cannot immediately use the feature once enabling it).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I searched the options using words like "package" "packages" "add", none of them leads to the correct option. I'd say the search option feature of VS needs to be improved...

Comment: I found this toggle, but it doesn't seem to do anything in my .Net Core 1.1 project. Then again, a lot of things don't seem to work in 2017 on my .Net Core project. After creating a Razor View, I have to close and open the view for Intellisense to work. After adding a NuGet package, I have to close and open the solution to get Inellisense on Startup.cs.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this option only exists for VS2017 on Windows. There is no such option like this for the Mac version.